# Как пользователю запретить просматривать HTML код webBrowser в Winform?

Tags: c#, winforms

Как сделать, чтобы пользователь не мог смотреть код элемента webBrowser в Winform?[image]

```
namespace test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            this.label1.Text="Загрузка";



            webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.youtube.com/");
            this.label1.Visible=false;



        }

    }
}
```

Comment: [IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.iswebbrowsercontextmenuenabled?view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Forms_WebBrowser_IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, а горячие клавиши?

Comment: @Grundy Мне кажется автору этого будет вполне достаточно. Ну а вообще, не тот он компонент изначально выбрал для подобных целей (ИМХО).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, спасибо большое, а какой компонент вы бы посоветовали ? И еще не могли бы подсказать как пройти программную аутентификацию на сайте ?

Comment: @Artyom Все зависит от задачи, которую вы решаете. Если просто получить данные с сайта, то тут вообще не нужен браузер; Если у вас задача написать свой удобный обозреватель, то возьмите Chromium и на его основе пишите что надо; Если вам нужна автоматизация (автоматические тесты сайта(ов)), то для таких задач существует Selenium.